# Accessing scrollbars in QScrollarea causes a runtime fault

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

Having some issues with QScrollAreas..

I want to be able to dynamically enable/disable scrollbars, and as such I tried implementing

```
scrollArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);`
```

This causes the application to terminate with code 255 and output nothing. Output is fine with this line commented out. I can use:

```
scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(0);
```

without a problem too. I tried subclassing a custom QScrollArea to see if that would let me modify the qscrollbar, but same issue. scrollArea is contructed on a ui form and re-parented within a custom displayWindow class.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show your code. Oh, an the problem *isn't* a compilation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you construct a scroll area within a ui form and then re-parent it somewhere else? Not that it's a problem, but it makes little sense to do so. You are aware, I hope that Qt Designer allows you to use custom classes, even without writing any plugins.

I can't reproduce your problem, though. Please create a [sscce](http://www.sscce.org) that reproduces it. Make sure that `scrollArea` is not a `nullptr`. I bet it is, or it's a dangling pointer (pointer to deallocated memory). The below works *fine* on both Qt 4 and Qt 5. The horizontal scroll bar *is* suppressed as desired.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QScopedPointer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QScopedPointer<QScrollArea> area (new QScrollArea);
    QLabel * label = new QLabel(QString(300, 'm'));
    area->setWidget(label);
    area->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    area->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my confusing description, self-taught C++/Qt programmer...
The scroll area is constructed within a ui form and a pointer member is set as a handle within displaywindow. No actual re-partenting.

Checking pointers was a good starting point, passing the scrollArea pointer to child widgets was causing a problem. Just because the pointer is public doesn't mean the ui-constructed qscrollarea is public...oops. Solved by using a child widget signal and modifying qscrollarea within its parent widget only.

Comment: @user2546108: I have no idea what you're talking about. There's no such thing as a non-public object but a public pointer. The entire thing you're talking about is a made-up construct. In this case, it doesn't matter where in the code you access something, if the compiler doesn't complain and you're in the same thread, you're OK.